# How can I use thresholding to improve image quality after rotating an image with skimage.transform?

Tags: python, opencv, mnist

I have the following image:

[Initial Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yACz0.png)

I am using the following code the rotate the image:

```
from skimage.transform import rotate
image = cv2.imread('122.png')
rotated = rotate(image,34,cval=1,resize = True)
```

Once I execute this code, I receive the following image:

[Rotated Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDVYH.png)

To eliminate the blur on the image, I use the following code to set a threshold. Anything that is not white is turned to black (so the gray spots turn black). The code for that is as follows:

```
ret, thresh_hold = cv2.threshold(rotated, 0, 100, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
plt.imshow(thresh_hold)
```

Instead of getting a nice clear picture, I receive the following:

[Choppy Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xXQ8.png)

Does anyone know what I can do to improve the image quality, or adjust the threshold to create a clearer image?

I attempted to adjust the threshold to different values, but this changed the image to all black or all white.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach that is to simply antialias the image in Python/OpenCV.

To do that one simply converts to grayscale. Then blurs the image, then applies a stretch of the image.

Adjust the blur sigma to change the antialiasing.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# load image
img = cv2.imread('122.png')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur threshold image
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (0,0), sigmaX=2, sigmaY=2, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

# stretch so that 255 -> 255 and 127.5 -> 0
result = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(blur, in_range=(127.5,255), out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)

# save output
cv2.imwrite('122_antialiased.png', result)

# Display various images to see the steps
cv2.imshow('result', result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]